# ASP.NET Core Identity 3.1: UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync always returns UserNotInRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1, role-manager

Im able to create roles using role manager and add user to a role using **UserManager.AddToRoleAsync**
But when using method **UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(User, Role)**, im always getting error saying ***UserNotInRole***

[image]

- But when using **UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Administrator")**, I'm getting results.
  [image]
- But again method **UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Administrator");** return false.
- Next, upon checking on the SQL profiler, I noticed that parameters set for userId & roleid is opposite during select statement of **UserInRole** table
  [image]

Any idea what is causing this weird behaviour? Im using Identity.Core, Version=3.1.3.0

***Updated the code snippet***

My AspNetUserole Table

[image]

Refer to below image, only methods IsInRoleAsync & RemoveFromRoleAsync get fails, other methods are getting results.

[image]

Comment: Show us your AspNetUserRoles table , and also confirm that your admin/user from AddToRoleAsync  is correctly get the user .

Comment: @NanYu I've update the details. Please advise what I'm missing here.

Comment: So AspNetUserRoles  have correct user and role mapping ? What if create a new role and user to test , same result ?

Comment: Yes same issue for new role too. Found similar problem reported 
[link](https://github.com/alexandre-spieser/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore/issues/22) but in older version
@NanYu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your keys for the identity *UserRole* table is configured wrongly.
Can post the code snippet where you have modified the *IdentityUserRole* table?

It should be like following configuration

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable("Rmit.UserRole").HasKey(k => new {  k.UserId,k.RoleId });
```

Comment: protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityMigration());
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleMigration());

            //Rename tables
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable("Rmit.UserRole").HasKey(k => new { k.RoleId, k.UserId });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().ToTable("Rmit.UserClaim");
    }

Comment: @sthashakun can check your userRole key mapping? From the above image regarding parameters of columns userId & roleid, try changing to

`builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable("Rmit.UserRole").HasKey(k => new {  k.UserId,k.RoleId });`

Comment: You were correct it was causing the issue. Thanks a lot.